# Pivot Table Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

```
class Project extends Eloquent {

       public function users()
       {
         return $this->belongsToMany('User','project_user','project_id','user_id')
         ->withPivot('isLeader');
       }
 }

 class User extends Eloquent {
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project','project_user','project_id','user_id')
        ->withPivot('isLeader');
    }
 }
```

my pivot table name is project_user with an extra column "isLeader"..

when I try to attach:

```
 $user= User::findOrFail($user_id);
 $user->projects()->attach($project_id);
```

It doesn't work.. I got this error

```
  Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key   
  constraint fails (`db`.`project_user`, CONSTRAINT `project_user_project_id_foreign` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`)REFERENCES `projects` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert 
  into `project_user` () values ())
```

However, if I use $projects->user()->attach('userid') instead, it works.

But, I need to fetch $user->projects()... but it is not working.

Comment: Problem was setting up the relationship..

         return $this->belongsToMany('Project','project_user','project_id','user_id')
         ->withPivot('isLeader');

should be..

        return $this->belongsToMany('Project','project_user','user_id','project_id')
         ->withPivot('isLeader');

O.O

Comment: Maybe you can post this as an answer for future reference.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation. Please do it for me. Tnx

Comment: You can answer it, you don't need rep for this to answer and if you answer it then someone may up vote it or maybe I, so your rep will increase. You can even accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was setting up the relationship..

```
     return $this->belongsToMany('Project','project_user','project_id','user_id')
     ->withPivot('isLeader');
```

should be..

```
    return $this->belongsToMany('Project','project_user','user_id','project_id')
     ->withPivot('isLeader');
```

O.O